# Pytorch ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list & ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, optimization, parameters, pytorch

When trying to create a neural network and optimize it using Pytorch, I am getting the error messages as follows,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 312, in <module>
    trainer = ProxylessDetTrainer(model,
  File "search.py", line 243, in __init__
    torch.optim.Adam(params=[m.alpha for _, m in self.nas_modules],
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/adam.py", line 48, in __init__
    super(Adam, self).__init__(params, defaults)
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 50, in __init__
    raise ValueError("optimizer got an empty parameter list")
ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/pin_memory.py", line 25, in _pin_memory_loop
    r = in_queue.get(timeout=MP_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL)
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 116, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/python3.8/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 282, in rebuild_storage_fd
    fd = df.detach()
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 57, in detach
    with _resource_sharer.get_connection(self._id) as conn:
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 87, in get_connection
    c = Client(address, authkey=process.current_process().authkey)
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 508, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 751, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 414, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Here is the code.

main.py

```
trainer = ProxylessDetTrainer(model,
                                          args=args,
                                          hyp=hyp,
                                          loss=compute_loss,
                                          optimizer=optimizer,
                                          imgsz=imgsz,
                                          imgsz_test=imgsz_test,
                                          train=train_loader,
                                          dataset=dataset,
                                          test=test_loader,
                                          writer=writer,
                                          lf=lf,
                                          scheduler=scheduler,
                                          num_epochs=epochs,
                                          arc_learning_rate=args['arch_lr'],
                                          target_prob=args['target_prob'],
                                          device=device)
```

search.py

```
class ProxylessDetTrainer(BaseOneShotTrainer):
    def __init__(self, model, args, hyp, loss, optimizer, imgsz, imgsz_test,
                 train, dataset, test, writer, lf, scheduler, num_epochs,
                 arc_learning_rate=1.0E-3, target_prob=0.5, device=None):
        self.model = model
        self.args = args
        self.hyp = hyp
        self.loss = loss
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.image_size = imgsz
        self.image_size_test = imgsz_test
        self.train_loader = train
        self.dataset = dataset
        self.test_loader = test
        self.test_loader_iterator = iter(self.test_loader)
        self.writer = writer
        self.lf = lf
        self.scheduler = scheduler
        self.epochs = num_epochs
        self.target_prob = target_prob
        self.device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available()
                                   else 'cpu') if device is None else device
        self.num_workers = self.train_loader.num_workers
        self.exit_flag = False

        print(f'Hyperparameters {self.hyp}')
        self.log_dir = Path(self.writer.logdir)
        # weights directory
        self.wdir = str(self.log_dir / 'weights') + os.sep
        os.makedirs(self.wdir, exist_ok=True)
        self.last = self.wdir + 'last.pt'
        self.best = self.wdir + 'best.pt'
        self.results_file = str(self.log_dir / 'results.txt')
        self.batch_size, self.total_batch_size, self.rank = \
            args['batch_size'], args['total_batch_size'], args['global_rank']

        # Save run settings
        with open(self.log_dir / 'hyp.yaml', 'w') as f:
            yaml.dump(self.hyp, f, sort_keys=False)
        with open(self.log_dir / 'args.yaml', 'w') as f:
            yaml.dump(self.args, f, sort_keys=False)

        self.cuda = self.device.type != 'cpu'
        init_seeds(2 + self.rank)
        with open(args['data_cfg']) as f:
            data_dict = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

        # number classes, names
        self.nc, self.names = (1, ['item']) if self.args['single_cls'] \
            else (int(data_dict['nc']), data_dict['names'])
        assert len(self.names) == self.nc, \
            '%g names found for nc=%g dataset in %s' % \
            (len(self.names), self.nc, self.args['data_cfg'])  # check

        self.model.to(self.device)
        self.nas_modules = []
        replace_layer_choice(self.model, ProxylessLayerChoice,
                             self.nas_modules)
        replace_input_choice(self.model, ProxylessInputChoice,
                             self.nas_modules)
        for _, module in self.nas_modules:
            module.to(self.device)

        self.ctrl_optim = \
            torch.optim.Adam([m.alpha for _, m in self.nas_modules],
                             arc_learning_rate, weight_decay=0,
                             betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-8)
```

adam.py

```
class Adam(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, params, lr=1e-3, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-8,
                 weight_decay=0, amsgrad=False):
        if not 0.0 <= lr:
            raise ValueError("Invalid learning rate: {}".format(lr))
        if not 0.0 <= eps:
            raise ValueError("Invalid epsilon value: {}".format(eps))
        if not 0.0 <= betas[0] < 1.0:
            raise ValueError("Invalid beta parameter at index 0: {}".format(betas[0]))
        if not 0.0 <= betas[1] < 1.0:
            raise ValueError("Invalid beta parameter at index 1: {}".format(betas[1]))
        if not 0.0 <= weight_decay:
            raise ValueError("Invalid weight_decay value: {}".format(weight_decay))
        defaults = dict(lr=lr, betas=betas, eps=eps,
                        weight_decay=weight_decay, amsgrad=amsgrad)
        super(Adam, self).__init__(params, defaults)
```

optimizer.py

```
class Optimizer(object):
    
    def __init__(self, params, defaults):
        torch._C._log_api_usage_once("python.optimizer")
        self.defaults = defaults

        self._hook_for_profile()

        if isinstance(params, torch.Tensor):
            raise TypeError("params argument given to the optimizer should be "
                            "an iterable of Tensors or dicts, but got " +
                            torch.typename(params))

        self.state = defaultdict(dict)
        self.param_groups = []

        param_groups = list(params)
        if len(param_groups) == 0:
            raise ValueError("optimizer got an empty parameter list")
        if not isinstance(param_groups[0], dict):
            param_groups = [{'params': param_groups}]

        for param_group in param_groups:
            self.add_param_group(param_group)
```

**How to make my network have parameters like the linked example?**

Thank you!

I tried the additional work as follows, but it doesn't work well..

In "search.py"

```
self.ctrl_optim = \
            torch.optim.Adam(params=[m.alpha for _, m in self.nas_modules],
                             lr=arc_learning_rate, weight_decay=0,
                             betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-8)
```